# WordPress: "All" filter is not working on admin listing page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using plugin for WooCommcerce Subscription https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions.

All other filters are working fine except `All` filter is not showing any records.

is there any way around to solve this from theme's `functions.php`?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Wordpress & WooCommerde do you use?

Comment: Updated one, BTW thanks I have resolved it by putting this code in ```functions.php``` ```function filter_by_status( $query ) {
  global $pagenow;
  // Get the post type
  $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : false;
  if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_subscription' ) {
      $query->query_vars['post_status'] = 'any';
  }
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_by_status' );```

Comment: Because it looked like the following issue with a previous version https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22271. Nice to hear that it has been solved, can you post your code as an answer to your question so that you eventually can mark it as resolved? 
It is not a good idea to add more extensive code as a comment because of the legibility that is lost, Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting following code in theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function filter_by_status( $query ) {
  global $pagenow;
  // Get the post type
  $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : false;
  $status = isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) ? $_GET['post_status'] : false;
  if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_subscription' && (!$status || $status == 'all') ) {
      $query->query_vars['post_status'] = 'any';
  }
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_by_status' );
```